# Initialize the Fire SDK on Unity for IOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I just started a project in Unity and I integrated FireBase Analytics.
After some problems I was able to get data from IOS and Android devices so I added some custom events.
I followed the instructions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/events) and I stared to see results in the dashboard . My problem is that I'm not sure if both IOS and Android are sending the events and I don't know how to separate the event in the dashboard. I'm particularly concerned because I'm not sure if I misunderstood this line of the instructions:

> The Firebase Unity SDK on Android requires Google Play services, which must be up-to-date before the SDK can be used. The following code should be added at the start of your application to check for and optionally update Google Play ....

I assumed that the following code had to be added ONLY for Android so I didn't add it to IOS. Can you tell me if I had add this code for IOS too? and how can I check the events for every OS?

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
  if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
    // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp, i.e.
    //   app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
    // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.

    // Set a flag here indicating that Firebase is ready to use by your
    // application.
  } else {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
      "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
    // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was looking for all the day and I found that the filter between OS is in the top left corner of dashboard and event tap as well.
I also used the code for both IOS and Android and I started to get custom event in IOS too.